# My eventlistener is not working with selected class

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a problem I am trying to log all my classes that's called "info" with eventlistener but it's not working. I have no idea why.

This is my javascript code:

```
const infoBox = document.querySelectorAll(".info");

for (var i = 0; i < infoBox.length; i++) {
    infoBox[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
}
```

Then I have multiple classes of where the class "info" is included:

```
<section class="shop-card">
                <section class="item">
                    <figure>
                        <img class="shop-img" src="./Images/Screenshot_27.png" alt="">
                    </figure>
                </section>
                <section class="info">
                    <section class="price">
                        <p>$15</p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="buy-btn">
                        <p class="button">Kopen</p>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
```

If I run this nothing is happening, anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking them? The code is fine, it should work.

Comment: Do the elements exist at the time the code is run? (If this is run before the document is complete, your selector may return no elements)

Comment: @DBS I tried to put the same code in my html file in a <script> tag and it works fine. How do I let it work properly in my JS file? My file is linked at the end of my body

Comment: @DBS yeah there was another JS code that was interfering, ty for helping man! It works now